# OpenCV Error: Bad flag

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm working in opencv on some methodes but keep getting the following error:

```
OpenCV Error: Bad flag(parameter or structure field) (unrecognized or unsupported array)
```

Here is the code:

```
void RafiTextLineExtractor::eraseMargins(){


    Mat img = _image.clone();
    threshold(img, img, 100, 200, CV_THRESH_BINARY_INV);

    BinaryComponentExtractor bn;
    bn.setImage(&DImage(img));
    vector<ConnectedComponent*> components;

    bn.extract(components);

    namedWindow("components",CV_WINDOW_NORMAL);
    imshow("components", img);

}

void  BinaryComponentExtractor::extract(vector<ConnectedComponent*>& components){
    vector<vector<Point>> contours;
    vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;
    Mat mat = _image->getMat().clone();
    cv::findContours(mat, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_TREE, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE, Point(0, 0) );
    collectComponents(contours, hierarchy, components);
} 

void setImage(DImage* img) { _image = img; }
```

Also, when I debug the project it does not seem to pass the image (in `bn.setImage()`..) any Ideas why that happens?

regards.

Comment: oh yeah fixed it, still getting the error.

Answer (score 0):

your function returns None. so you're trying to show None.

Comment: The problem is not with me NOT SEEING anything its with the function not passing a Mat properly.

Comment: Whole code plz, so can see that wat r u passing in that function.